# header + sticky sidebars

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a 3 column webpage with sticky side bars + sticky header and footer, however I'm having issues as the sidebars goes above my header. What I want to accomplish is the sidebars floating under the header, and the **only** element moving when scrolling is the middle section.

```css
div.sticky-header {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.main, .side-left, .side-right {
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.main {
  width: 90%;
  height: 150vh;
}

.side-left, .side-right {
  width: 10%;
  height: 25vh;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #ccc;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="sticky-header">I will stick to the screen when you reach my scroll position</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="side-left">
    left
    </div>

    <div class="main">
    middle stuff
  </div>

      <div class="side-right">
        right
        </div>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jbnak12c/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you already found the answer but for those who might also be having a look at this question z-index: 10; in div.sticky-header would do the trick.